# How do you know what goes in the top or side of a crud matrix

Tags: database-design, crud, diagram, use-case

No where I've red actually explain what goes on the top versus the side of a crud matrix?
For example [here](http://blog.aplikacja.info/2011/12/crud-matrix-as-a-software-design-and-estimation-tool/), why is "Product", "Order", "Item", "Payment" and "ERP Order" along the top? Why is "add product" on the side? What is the rule being used? Is it that the functions you are planning to implement are on the side and the data store you get it from is on the top?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't really matter and there is no single standard way to do it.  It depends on context,  personally I usually put the (Create, Read, Update, Delete) activities along the top and the domain object (or tables) down the side.  However another common format is to place the scenarios/usecases down the side, the domain objects along the top and the crud activity in the box.  The key thing is to ask your self why you are doing the CRUD matrix.  To analyse the problem, clarify your understanding, record progress, demonstrate test coverage, convey information to a third party.  Then decide which format is most appropriate for that objective.  Don't get hung up on form, get hung up on objective.